# Websocket with apache vhosts

Tags: php, apache, websocket, vhosts, ratchet

I have two apache virtual hosts for two different applications:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername socket1.app
    DocumentRoot d:\xampp\htdocs\socket1.app
    <Directory d:\xampp\htdocs\socket1.app>
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername socket2.app
    DocumentRoot d:\xampp\htdocs\socket2.app
    <Directory d:\xampp\htdocs\socket2.app>
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I open http://socket1.app it send connect request to ws://socket1.app:8080 and
http://socket2.app send to ws://socket2.app:8080.

A have php server services for both applications based on [ratchet php](http://socketo.me/). 
But applications connect to the same php server(which has been started first).

How I can divide this sockets connections to each app php server service?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two websocket server instances running on the same port.

You have to either run them on different ports (e.g. 8080 and 8081), or divide the app logic based on the host name.

In RatchetPHP you can do it like this:

```
public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $conn, $msg)
{
    // The host name that the client connected to (socket1.app or socket2.app)
    $host = $conn->WebSocket->request->getHost();

    // ... some logic depending on the host name
    // if ($host == 'socket1.app')
    // { 
    // ...
    // }
}
```

The first approach is preferable if your websocket apps have totally different logic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already use different ports for applications. About your code block, I need not to check host in code, because applications are absolutely different.